# Voltage specification on schematic

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic

[DX7 Schematic](https://ia803205.us.archive.org/5/items/DX7SCHEMATICS/DX7_SCHEMATICS.pdf) A/D converter VCC and Reference is shown as 5A instead of +5. What does the A mean? Also, it's regulator is listed as +5AV.

Comment: Add the schematic you're referring to to your question.

Comment: In that context, "A" usually refers to "analog". It is expected that it will be kept separate from the power for digital circuits.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AD converter is powered by 5V and since that 5V is generated from 15V supply with a separate regulator and used only for analog components the regulator is called +5AV regulator because it is the regulator for 5V analog voltage and the output i called it is called +5A to make it clear it is the 5V analog supply which is different from the digital +5 supply.